# Log-in Issue when using CTRL+ALT+F1 - password is automatically entered

Tags: login

The issue I'm running into is when I try to enter the CLI using CTRL+ALT+F1 or CTRL+ALT+F3, I get the log-in screen and am prmopted for my username.  After entering my username the cursor hops to the next line, the text I enter is displayed on the screen, then it tells me that I entered the wrong password.  If I don't enter anything, the cursor hops to the next line, and after a few seconds it tells me wrong password.

The other detail is that the loop happens about 3 or 4 times until I am prompted for my password again.  I looked through the forum and couldn't find a problem.

I checked my .bashrc but the only thing that is different is I have some GCP stuff there. I commented out all the new lines in my bashrc file that were new and this still happens.

This is using Ubuntu 16.04